# How can I get this Regex outprint?

Tags: php, regex

I've a problem with my regex in php. I need this for some evaluation, and it would be much easier if I could change this regex to the right. The final array I convert with `json_encode` to a JSON-File.

I've already tried a lot different regex but I never get the right output. Now I get something like this:

```
[
    [
    "234445 01:00:34.423 ineedhelpineedhelpineedhelppls",
    "234445 03:04:24.932 sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid",
    ],
    [
    "234445 ",
    "234445 "
    ],
    [
    "01:00:34.423",
    "01:00:34.423"
    ],
    [
    "ineedhelpineedhelpineedhelppls",
    "sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid"
    ]

]
```

My regex looks like this:
`preg_match_all('/(^\d+\s)(01:\w+\S\w+\S\w+)(\s.+)/im', $data, $matches)`

If could something like this would be really nice:

```
[
    [
    "234445 01:00:34.423 ineedhelpineedhelpineedhelppls",
    "234445",
    "01:00:34.423",
    "ineedhelpineedhelpineedhelppls"
    ],
    [
    "234445 03:04:24.932 sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid",
    "234445 ",
    "01:00:34.423",
    "sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid"
    ]

]
```

The .log File looks something like this:

```
234445 03:04:24.932 sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid
234445 03:04:24.932 sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid
234445 03:04:24.932 sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid
234445 03:04:24.932 sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid
234445 03:04:24.932 sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid
234445 03:04:24.932 sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid
234445 03:04:24.932 sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid
234445 03:04:24.932 sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid
234445 03:04:24.932 sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid
234443 03:04:24.932 sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid
```

Comment: Please _don't_ try to use regex to parse JSON.  Use a proper JSON parser instead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I dont parse JSON, I parse a .log File

Comment: Is it a long log file? Would you mind sharing it here so we can test it too.

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan I could give you a similiare file, with other data

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan I edit it

Comment: And what exactly you want to get?

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan You can see it in the question

Comment: You said ```something like this``` but did not explain what do you expect. If you say that too, we can help better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag to [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$data = '234445 01:00:34.423 ineedhelpineedhelpineedhelppls
234445 03:04:24.932 sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid';
preg_match_all('/(^\d+\s)(\d+:\w+\S\w+\S\w+)(\s.+)/im', $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [0] => 234445 01:00:34.423 ineedhelpineedhelpineedhelppls
    [1] => 234445
    [2] => 01:00:34.423
    [3] => ineedhelpineedhelpineedhelppls
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [0] => 234445 03:04:24.932 sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid
    [1] => 234445
    [2] => 03:04:24.932
    [3] => sdfkkdkkddddddsdfsdfiieuwrepid
  )
)
```

Note that you also need to change `01` in your regex to `\d+` to match a time starting with e.g. `03`.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/RgmO2)